MQTT client connection error during publish ( return code -6)
I am trying to publish through MQTT using credential(username & password) in C on linux platform (ubuntu 18). But I am not able to make connection. I am getting error return code -6.This error return code is when i try to connect.
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "MQTTClient.h"

#define ADDRESS     "ssl://sample url"
#define CLIENTID    "12345"
#define TOPIC       "device/ankit/out"
#define PAYLOAD     "Hello World!"
#define QOS         1
#define TIMEOUT     10000L

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  
    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
    MQTTClient_SSLOptions sslOptions = MQTTClient_SSLOptions_initializer;

   
    rc=   MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
        MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_DEFAULT, NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 30;;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
     conn_opts.ssl = NULL;

    conn_opts.username = "<username>";
    //printf("%s",conn_opts.username);
    conn_opts.password = "<password>";
   rc= MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts);
     if (rc != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
{

   printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

    pubmsg.payload = PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = strlen(PAYLOAD);
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &token);
    printf("Waiting for up to %d seconds for publication of %s\n"
           "on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",
            (int)(TIMEOUT/1000), PAYLOAD, TOPIC, CLIENTID);
    rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, TIMEOUT);
    printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token);

    MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client);
   
    return rc;
}

build command
sudo gcc test.c -I/usr/include/json-c -lcurl -ljson-c -lpaho-mqtt3cs


Have you looked in the headers to see what -6 refers to

Also edit the question to be clear exactly where you are getting that return code

The description of what -6 means in the MQTTClient.h is pretty clear - https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/6b1e202a701ffcdaa277b5644ed291287a70a7aa/src/MQTTClient.h#L155

Hi the return code -6 means MQTTCLIENT_NULL_PARAMETER.I am getting this error code when trying to connect.

I have set all parameters , not sure which parameter it is taking null. Since I am not using certificates for ssl (only username & password), so ssl is kept NULL. Am I missing any parameter or doing it wrong?

What happens if you use the sslOptions strut you have created?
